"Get a box" article?
Been in "professional" aviation for 20Y. I recall an article where the author, an aviation manager, advocated for keeping a box in your office, for the purpose of packing all of your personal things the moment the job turned into something you didn't like / it wasn't supposed to be.
The overarching message was that your boss(es) needed to know that if your job became about something other than aviation safety, or whatever it's supposed to be, you're ready and willing to walk away at the drop of a hat.
Does anyone else remember this article and where it was published?

never heard of it, could apply to any business. But in reality it is more likely to give your boss the impression you're "not invested in the company" and "unreliable", excuses to fire you at the next performance review.

As a mind-set it might be beneficial, but I have a hard time seeing how keeping an actual physical box in your office would be valuable. Being willing to walk at any time is great but it's not like jobs don't know how to handle people resigning, and that includes how to get all their personal stuff out the door

This would appear to be just as applicable (or in applicable) to any job inside or outside aviation.

All good points. I think the article was from ~20Y ago when small to medium sized aviation operations were being told by customers and insurance companies that they had to have a director of safety, and DOs were hiring Safety mgrs to appease the requirements, but didn't want to hear a peep out of them. The collandar of my mind doesn't fully retain the article which is why I'd love to re-read it to see how accurately I recall it.
